# Why can't set ctrl+n as hot key to call dictionary completion?

Tags: dictionary, vim, completion

Two lines was set in .vimrc.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt set filetype=txt
autocmd FileType txt set dictionary+=$HOME/.vim/dict/mydict.dict
```

The dictionary completion can be called with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>and<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>.

I want to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> as call dictionary completion directly.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt set filetype=txt
autocmd FileType txt set dictionary+=k$HOME/.vim/dict/mydict.dict
```

It is verified that `set  dictionary+=k$HOME/.vim/dict/mydict.dict` can work.
Why  `autocmd FileType txt set dictionary+=k$HOME/.vim/dict/mydict.dict` can't work?

Comment: What do you expect that autocmd to do? That doesn't and won't handle any change of key mappings.

Answer (score 2):

The `dictionary` setting needs to be set to a comma separated list of file names to use for dictionary completion. Using `+=` is definitely the recommended way to add to this, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `+=k`?

To use `<c-n>` instead of `<c-x><c-k>`, simply map it in insert mode:

```
imap <c-n> <c-x><c-k>
```

This can be put in an autocmd similar to the dictionary setting you have already.